# Internal Server Error: Failed to Resolve Import Path in React App. Does the file exist?

Tags: reactjs, import, vite, importerror

I'm a beginner in React, and I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious here within this error:

"[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import '/components/navbar' from 'src/App.jsx'. Does the file exist?"

I've used a similar project structure in previous projects without any issues. My project structure is as follows:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwJd8.png)

I've tried:

- import { Navbar } from "./components/navbar";
- import { Navbar } from "/components/navbar";
- import { Navbar } from "/components/navbar/Navbar";

I've also tried moving the components folder out of the src folder.

I have attached screenshot of my workspace.

Thank you!

Comment: I have found that the problem was the way I was exporting and importing the component - Ensure that when using export default (what I did), the import statement should not include curly braces ({}) around the imported value. This is because export default exports a single default value, and curly braces are used for named exports. So, the correct import syntax is " import Navbar from './path/to/Navbar'".

Answer (score -1):

You have made a mistake in addressing. If you have a problem in addressing, just open the file you want to import and do not close it, and mention its name where you want to use it and you will receive the address ready. In this file, the name is enough. Replace `/components/navbar/Navbar >>>>  ./components/navbar/Navbar`